# Swift Action with key not working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, key, action

Well the title really says it all...
when I try to write the following code

```swift
ball.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone], withKey: "Action"))
```

it says...

```swift
extra argument in call runAction
```

How do I fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ball.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]), withKey: "Action")
```

Is the ")" in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you misplaced the parentheses. Try `ball.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]), withKey: "Action")`